# Using Pandas to use transaction history to determine no of shares

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transactions

So I'm trying to use the transaction history from Football Index to capture the number of shares in my portfolio.

Once I've downloaded the csv into python, created a dataframe within pandas and organised the data I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                   name              type  quantity
723  Alejandro Grimaldo          PURCHASE       100
303  Alejandro Grimaldo         BUY_LIMIT       101
301  Alejandro Grimaldo  BUY_LIMIT_CANCEL       101
721  Alejandro Grimaldo          PURCHASE       100
724  Alejandro Grimaldo          PURCHASE       200
285  Alejandro Grimaldo         BUY_LIMIT       100
276  Alejandro Grimaldo  BUY_LIMIT_CANCEL       100
662         Alex Telles          PURCHASE       200
711      Alexander Isak          PURCHASE       100
747     Alphonso Davies          PURCHASE       100
403            Angelino              SALE        29
```

I want to have a resulting data frame with columns 'Name' (with no duplicates like above) and 'No of Shares'.

The way the maths works for the shares no is:

```
no of shares = (PURCHASE) * quantity + (BUY_LIMIT)* quantity - SALE * quantity - BUY_LIMIT_CANCEL * quantity
```

From the table above the output I'd want is:

```
                   name       no of shares
723  Alejandro Grimaldo                400
662         Alex Telles                200
711      Alexander Isak                100
747     Alphonso Davies                100
403            Angelino                -29
...
```

How do I use pandas to create a new column that gives the sum of the values in 'quantity' where they're added or subtracted dependent on what is in 'type' and for each unique player in 'name'?

Part of what I wondered if it's best to create a multi-index to get rid of the player name duplication problem, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggFunc=sum` and `fill_value=0` to pivot the dataframe with index as `name` and columns as `type`, then apply the formula to calculate the `no of shares`:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='type',
                     values='quantity', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

df1['no of shares'] = df1['PURCHASE'] + \
    df1['BUY_LIMIT'] - df1['SALE'] - df1['BUY_LIMIT_CANCEL']

df1 = df1['no of shares'].reset_index()
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
                 name  no of shares
0  Alejandro Grimaldo           400
1         Alex Telles           200
2      Alexander Isak           100
3     Alphonso Davies           100
4            Angelino           -29
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be remapping the quantity and performing a `groupby` and `sum`

```
df['quantity'] = np.where(df.type.isin(['SALE', 'BUY_LIMIT_CANCEL']), df.quantity * -1, df.quantity)

print(df.groupby('name').sum())

# prints:

                   quantity
name               
Alejandro Grimaldo      400
Alex Telles             200
Alexander Isak          100
Alphonso Davies         100
Angelino                -29
```